# Correct way to download image and update ViewHolder

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I need to display items in a RecyclerView. I am using FirestoreRecyclerOptions to pass the data to the FirestoreRecyclerAdapter. However part of the data required are images that are stored in Firebase storage separately from the database documents. I have the images downloading and they are being set in the FirestoreRecyclerAdapter holder however I know it is not the correct way to do this. Any help with the correct way to do this would be appreciated.

Current onBindViewHolder in the FirestoreRecyclerAdapter that implements an interface for callback.

```
@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyListHolder holder, int position, @NonNull     TodoItem model) {
    // Get the 'to do' image from storage using the stored image reference from document.
    StorageReference imageReference = storageRef.child(model.getImageReference());
    ImageTransfer.imageDownload(this, holder, imageReference);

    holder.description.setText(model.getDescription());

    if (model.getMarkedDone().equals("true")) {
        holder.markedDone.setImageResource(R.drawable.mark_done_icon);
    }
    else {
        holder.markedDone.setImageResource(R.drawable.mark_not_done_icon);
    }

}
```

Current utility method to download the image and use a callback to the FirestoreRecyclerAdapter to set the image downloaded in the holder when it is finished downloading. I feel like the holder and reference to the FirestoreRecyclerAdapter should not be passed outside of the FirestoreRecyclerAdapter?

```
static public void imageDownload(FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<?, ?> firestoreRecyclerAdapter, RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, StorageReference imageStorageRef) {
    final long ONE_MEGABYTE = 1024 \* 1024;
    imageStorageRef.getBytes(ONE_MEGABYTE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener\<byte\[\]\>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(byte\[\] bytes) {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            ((DownloadCompleteCallback) firestoreRecyclerAdapter).downloadComplete(bitmap, holder);
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: "I know it is not the correct way to do this" Why not? What's the problem with how you do it now, given that it seems to work?

Comment: Just trying to follow convention. This is my solution for the problem. I have now made the utility class more generic by changing the types of the parameters but it just feels like it might not be the best or proper way to do this. I might be wrong though and wanted to ask the coding wizards of StackOverflow in case better ways of doing this exist.

Comment: "it just feels like it might not be the best or proper way" Why would think that? Besides that, what is wrong with your code that needs to be improved? What needs to be added, however, is to handle exceptions.

Comment: I think I have improved it now and am more happy with it. What I meant was it felt tightly coupled the way I had done it however I have made the parameters more generic and therefore the utility class feels more loosely coupled and more reusable like it should it do. Yeah you are right about the exception handling which is in place now. Thanks